# How can I clone other's jekyll theme from other's github?

Tags: github, jekyll

I am a jekyll beginner. How can I clone other's jekyll theme from other's github? For example, https://github.com/yihui/cn.git.

Answer (score 1):

See [Fork a repo / Clone your fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo).

Comment: If I fork other's repo, I will also copy his posts and many personal setting.

Comment: Your first clone will... clone the repo. Clone what's in the repo. Nothing more.